# Using Subject.toPromise and async/await until subject value change

Tags: typescript, async-await

I need to HttpClient.post a Question and associate Propositions in the same way. I try to use Subject.toPromise() and async/await instructions. I need to wait for the response of the Question post in order to have a Question.id and then I can post the Propositions.

```
async getNewQuestionId(): Promise<number> {
    const id: number = await this.subjectQuestionId.toPromise();
    return id;
}

/* Proposition post, trying to get the ID before sending the post */
async postProposition(proposition: Proposition) {
    const questionId = await this.getNewQuestionId();
...
}

/* Question post (callback) */
...
this.subjectQuestionId.next(response.id);
...
```

The script does not execute the post Proposition and seems to stop at the line:

```
const questionId = await this.getNewQuestionId();
```

But nothing else happens.
The Subject value is updated few seconds after.

Comment: What library are you using that has the `toPromise()` in it?

Comment: Hi @ShaunLuttin, I use Observable.ts from rxjs.

Comment: In fact, I wanted to find a solution directly with Promises. I initialized a class variable Promise, made await the Proposition post on it, and made Promise.resolve(returnedId) in the callback of the Question.post. But the Proposition does not wait... hehe ! Is there a lead to follow in this side ?